$4$ Die Sum equals $20$ - How to generalise it to $n$ die
Calculate the probability that when we roll $4$ fair $6$−sided die, the sum of their upfaces is $20$.
My Solution:
There exist only the following $5$ possible cases where the sum is $20$ in case of $4$ die rolled:
$ 2666, 3665, 4664, 4565, 5555$
Hence to get the probability, we multiply the number of different arrangements corresponding to each case with its probability:
$$P = \frac1{6^4} \cdot \big[{4 \choose 1} + {2\cdot{4 \choose 2}} + {4 \choose 2} + {2\cdot{4 \choose 2}} + 1 \big] = \frac{35}{1296}$$
Question: Is there a better way than the above brute force method to get the answer? This will surely become tedious to solve as the number of die that are rolled increases. For instance, say, we want to calculate the probability that the sum is $50$ when we roll $18$ fair $6$-sided die. How would we go about it then?
Follow up: Is there a generalisation for this? What is the probability that the sum is $k$ when $n$ fair $6$-sided die are rolled?

For small numbers of dice, if I have a computer algebra system handy, I'd use generating functions. For example, the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $\left(\frac{x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6}{6}\right)^{18}$ is $126513483013/11284439629824 \approx 0.011211$. For larger numbers of dice, I'd use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution. The sum of $18$ dice has a mean of $63$ and a variance of $105/2$, which yields a standard deviation of about $7.2457$. Applying the continuity correction, the probability of getting a $50$ is about $0.011030$, an error of less than $2$ percent.

@underflow can you explain how did you get that expression? Did you use generating functions as well just as suggested by the other comment?

@BrianTung I'm not very comfortable with generating functions. Can you write an answer explaining the definition of x and how you got that expression from scratch?

Can either of you please explain the intuition behind using generating functions in the present context? What exactly does x represent? How do you get the expression? Why do we want to know the coefficient of $x^{50}$?

Okay so if I want to get the probability of sum being, say, 9 in the case of 2 die. Then that would be the coefficient of $x^9$ in the expression, right?

Got it, just to confirm one more thing: In the wolfram link, you took the $20$th derivative of the expression and have divided the expression by $20!$ as well. This is so that both $20!'s$ cancel out and you are left with just the coefficient of $x^{20}$ from the original expression, correct?

This comment thread was very helpful, thank you. Just for closure purposes, can you write a short answer about this method? I'd prefer to accept an answer rather than close the question with no answers, in case someone finds themself at this question in the future.

Or nevermind, I'll write one on my own. It might be better for me

@underflow If you get time, please have a look through the answer and let me know if there are any conceptual errors.

Good point, added that as well.

Thanks to @underflow for their explanations in the comments:
This generalisation can be done using generating functions.
Let $x$ be some symbol. Consider the expression $\frac{+^2+^3+^4+^5+^6}6$, each exponent corresponds to a number rolled on the die. Here, each $x^k$ has coefficient $\frac16$, which is the probability the dice will roll that way.
Now, consider the case of rolling $2$ die. In this case the expression becomes, $\frac{+^2+^3+^4+^5+^6}6 \cdot \frac{+^2+^3+^4+^5+^6}6$.  Multiply it out and then let's say we want to calculate the probability of getting the sum to be 9. For example when we get a $3$ on the first die and $6$ on the second, it is represented by $x^3 \cdot x^6$. Hence, it is becomes evident that the coefficient of $x^9$ in the final expression will correspond to the required probability of getting the sum as 9.
Similarly, in the case of the problem asked: calculate the probability that the sum is 50 when we roll 18 fair 6-sided die, it is given by:
the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the expression ${\big(\frac{+^2+^3+^4+^5+^6}6}\big)^{18} $; which is found here

Generalising to answer the follow-up:
The probability that the sum is $k$ when $n$ fair $6$-sided die are rolled is given by:
the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expression ${\big(\frac{+^2+^3+^4+^5+^6}6}\big)^{n}$
